# Combinations and Probability

Tags: combinatorics

There are 50 balls in a bag. 10 of them are red, 30 of them are white, and 10 of them are blue. I choose three at random simultaneously. What is the probability that I chose precisely two colors?

I know that the amount of total possibilities is 50 C 3 but I dont quite get the language of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many ways can you chose only 1 color? $\binom{10}{3}+\binom{30}{3}+\binom{10}{3}$.

How many ways can you chose 3 colors? $10*30*10$

Therefore all other ways give you 2 colors. That is $\binom{50}{3}-\binom{10}{3}-\binom{30}{3}-\binom{10}{3}-(10*30*10)=12300$

SO the probability is $\dfrac{12300}{\binom{50}{3}}\approx 63 \%$

Comment: I wonder how many answers I would have wrong if it weren't for you, I think about 15. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Answer

10 Red, 30 White, 10 Blue

Probability of getting two Red = $\frac{10}{50}$*$\frac{9}{49}$*$\frac{40}{48}$

Probability of getting two White = $\frac{30}{50}$*$\frac{29}{49}$*$\frac{20}{48}$

Probability of getting two Blue = $\frac{10}{50}$*$\frac{9}{49}$*$\frac{40}{48}$

Add them up all and multiply by 3 because, for any three draws, you could have R,R,Diff, R,Diff,R and Diff,R,R and so is the case for the other two and that will be your required probability of choosing exactly two colors out of the 3 draws(I am assuming without replacement).

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, sometime MSE becomes a little bit of a race to score points!!!

Comment: My pleasure. It’s good to have both of the natural solutions represented among the answers.